# c++ pthread conditional signal

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am working on multithreading in C++ using pthread. My problem is I am using frames from webcam to perform feature extraction. The feature extraction routine takes around 4-5 seconds to perform the task. However, I want the video streaming to continue and wait for the signal from the Feature extraction routine telling to send another frame. I think there are 2 functions to use here but I am unsure of its implementation. Functions are : **pthread_cond_wait** and  **pthread_cond_signal**.

My program outline is as follows:

```
void *makefeature(void * arg){
// compute future using surf
//HERE I WANT TO SIGNAL TO THE MAIN THAT I AM DONE SEND A NEW FRAME NOW
}

int main(){
// All video streaming functions and all
pthread_create(); //! call to make feature routine
}
```

How can I implement the 2 instance of pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal.Please help

Comment: Consider using boost threads - it would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Or [C++11 standard threading library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread), if you have access to C++11

Answer (score 1):

Independent of which library to use, the idea of condition variables is that 1 thread waits in a blocking state for a condition to change, so it doesn't have to poll it.  Since you want your streamer to continue, it might as well poll the condition each time, so you only need a mutex to synchronize the condition.

so extracter:

```
doExtraction(Frame);
mutex.lock();
Ready = true;
mutex.unlock();  // can be avoided with RAII
```

streamer:

```
while(true)
{
  doStreaming();
  bool localReady;
  mutex.lock();
  localReady = Ready;
  Ready = false;
  mutex.unlock();
  if (localReady) prepareFrame();
}
```

You might want to you a condition variable to pass the frame to the extractor thread.

Comment: According to your pseducode, I am bit confused as why should the bool variables do on mutex lock. Besides, my aim is to signal to the main() to send another frame without having to sit on the loop and wait. Basically, I am unable to tell the function when the feature extraction is done. I used bool to do that but than it didn't better my results.

Comment: In the streamer, Ready is first copied and then set to false, if that is not protected, then the extractor can set Ready to true between the 2 actions from the streamer, causing the Ready true to be not seen.  Also keep in mind that for multithreading, different optimizations can cause that updating a variable in 1 thread will be unnoticed in the other; mutexes are 1 of the possibilities to avoid this.

Comment: About the rest of your comment, I answered the question.  It didn't mention doing something in main() at that time.  cv's are about blocking until a condition is met.  Do you want the streamer to block or do you want to continue and poll the condition (e.g. when a frame is ready for the extraction)?

Comment: i want the streamer to continue

Comment: So my suggestion is then to check the ready flag when a frame is ready to be sent to the extracter without using a condition variable.